# code to find the unix timestamp of 60 minutes after the current time in php

Tags: php

echo strtotime("now") 
 and it gives output of a current Unix timestamp but what write when to find the unix timestamp of 60 minutes after the current time in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
time() + 3600; // i.e. 60 * 60; seconds
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Comment: tnx @ED Heal , got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try with -

`strtotime("+ 60 minutes");`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo strtotime("+60 minutes");
```

[PHP strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)